# High volume data processing using lower RAM size without standard java libraries

Tags: java, bigdata

In one of the technical discussion, I was asked a solution for the below scenario without using any standard java libraries which handles similar situation

1. how do you process an array which does not fit in available memory for JVM
2. how do you process a big file say 20 gb which does not fit in available memory.

I can possibly think of the following solutions

1. get the length of the array and process the array using some part of the length(for ex 4 iterations on array with length/4)
2. original file can be split into multiple parts using split command (or something similar in respective OS environment). Process individual smaller files and generate the intermediate result (for example data aggregation). Once individual file processing is done then based on the final size of the intermediate result files, process all the result file in 1 go or again apply iterative processing.

However I would like to know if there is a better approach. Also if such questions are inappropriate for this forum then please let me know and I will delete the question.
While I found some google articles with a solution but it talks of solution already provided by some libraries and hence posting it here.

Comment: How do you think this was done in the very old days with very little memory but ample storage?

Comment: [External sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) is an example of what you are describing.

Comment: It very much depends on what "process" means.  If "process" is such that one linear path through the data is sufficient, then that is easier than having to make arbitrary and random accesses to array elenents.

Comment: May I know why the question was given a negative count?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question is perfectly fine to be asked here as you can read on this [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be off-heap memory. Which could be mapped to direct memory or disk. You can get some inspiration here
https://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2012/10/compact-off-heap-structurestuples-in.html

Comment: if you want to scale well, try to decouple storage and compute. You can look into various cloud storage or open sources dbs.(sql or nosql) as per the read and write patterns. Read a bit about CAP theorm if you are no familiar with that.